# C# Sending value from WebSocket Server Thread to Main()

Tags: c#, multithreading, websocket, event-handling, iot

I am trying to write a program to control home automation devices. This involves a `WebSocket` server that runs infinitely in a background thread listening for clients. The client sends JSON packets that contain settings. When the server gets a JSON packet, I want it to read and change any settings as needed in the `Main()`

I have a working `WebSocket` server and I have tried to use the `PropertyChangedEvent` but it never seems to see the handler. I suspect this occurs because they exist in different threads.

I have attached my code below as well as the example I have been working off of. There is a chance I am way off the mark here but this is the best I could find with the reading I have been doing.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is the Main():

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace HomeAutomation
{
    class Controller
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool passGo = false;
            Thread SocketThread = new Thread(Socket.WebSocketServer);
            SocketThread.IsBackground = true;
            SocketThread.Start();

            //This line lets the user know the Socket Thread is running in the background
            Console.WriteLine("Socket Thread is running in the background: {0}", SocketThread.IsBackground);
            do {

                char input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
                if (input == 'x')
                {
                    passGo = true;
                }
            } while (passGo == false);
            Console.ReadLine();
            /*
            Settings s = new Settings();
            s.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(S_PropertyChanged);
            while (true)
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                s.State = str;
            }*/
        }

        public static void S_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Settings RecSettings = (Settings)sender;

            Console.WriteLine("The {0} has changed to {1}", e.PropertyName, RecSettings.State);
        }

    }

    public class Settings : INotifyPropertyChanged
    //The Class Object 'Settings' is used to recieve the variable(s) from the client software
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        #endregion

        string state = string.Empty;
        public string State
        {
            get { return state; }
            set
            {
                state = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("State"));
                    Console.WriteLine("Event has been called");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my webSocket:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace HomeAutomation
{
    class Socket
    {
        public static void WebSocketServer()
        {
            //Declaring variables used in the program
            IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost").AddressList[0];
            TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ipAddress, 8080);

            try
            {
                //Starts the server
                server.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Starting Server...");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //If the server cannot start the error will be caught and printed to console
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            while (true)
            {
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                MakeNewConnection(client);
            }
        }

        public static void MakeNewConnection(TcpClient client)
        {
            var thread = new Thread(NewClient);
            thread.Start(client);
        }

        public static void NewClient(object data)
        {
            var client = (TcpClient)data;
            Settings RecSettings = new Settings();

            //Lets you know the address of the connected client
            string address = client.Client.AddressFamily.ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("{0} has connected!", address);

            //creates a network stream for information to flow through
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            byte[] receivedBuffer = new byte[100];
            stream.Read(receivedBuffer, 0, receivedBuffer.Length);

            StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (byte b in receivedBuffer)
            {
                if (b.Equals(00))
                {
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    msg.Append(Convert.ToChar(b).ToString());
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Client Says: {0}", msg.ToString());

            RecSettings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(msg.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(RecSettings.State.ToString());

            RecSettings.State = "Off";

            int byteCount = Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount("Thank you");
            byte[] sendData = new byte[byteCount];
            sendData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Thank you");
            stream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the event handler example I am using:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace HomeAutomation
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestClass sample = new TestClass();
            sample.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(sample_PropertyChanged);
            while (true)
            {
                string str = Console.ReadLine();
                int val;
                if (int.TryParse(str, out val))
                    sample.TestValue = val;
            }
        }

        static void sample_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TestClass sample = (TestClass)sender;
            /*
             * Use expression behind if you have more the one property instead sample.TestValue
             * typeof(TestClass).GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetValue(sample, null)*/
            Console.WriteLine("Value of property {0} was changed! New value is {1}", e.PropertyName, sample.TestValue);
        }
    }

    public class TestClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        #endregion

        int testValue = 0;
        public int TestValue
        {
            get { return testValue; }
            set
            {
                testValue = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestValue"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to wrap the contents of your WebSocket response in code that invokes it in the Dispatcher thread.

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
     ... response handler code

}
```